# How to get apache server to send specific header

Tags: javascript, apache, soap, server

I have an apache 2.2 server with the app deployed. it has accessable from outer ip's simple soap API. SOAP queries being send via soapUI are processed correctly but being called from javascript like this:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
```

I get the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https:*url*?wsdl. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.

So I've found that I need to get apache 2.2 server to send

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin

header, but how?

or maybe it must be configured on the app side?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apache+header&t=hn&ia=about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting headers is relatively trivial.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

You will probably want to wrap it in a `<Location>`, `<Directory>` or `<File>` block.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' require configuration only in server side?

Comment: @LucasCosta – Of course. It would be pretty stupid for a JavaScript program to be able to grant *itself* permission to read data from another server.

Comment: em... where it must be written?

Comment: In your Apache configuration (for the server hosting `https:url?wsdl`)

Comment: @Quentin I've added   >Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to my server's httpd.conf  inside <Directory>  sections but now I can't even start server

Comment: @NikitinMikhail and what does the error log say? Directory is a valid context for Header directive.

Comment: @ezra-s that's the problem that I don't see new records in the error.log. The last records in the log file are: '' [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
 [notice] Child 3588: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[notice] Child 3588: Released the start mutex
 [notice] Child 3588: All worker threads have exited.
[notice] Child 3588: Child process is exiting
 [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.

Comment: @NikitinMikhail run "apachectl -t" for a syntax check. You touched something else you didn't mention, and we can't guess with this little information.

Comment: @ezra-s I've found. .conf test tells "Invalid command 'Header'"

Comment: Fantastic, that just means you haven't loaded mod_headers.so. Make sure you load it and problem solved.